# How to wait for return to be clicked with the entry widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

I am just trying to make a non-graphic game in Tkinter but am having trouble with the entry widget.  How can I wait for `"<Return>"` to be pressed before printing something?

```
    from Tkinter import *

    class App:
        def __init__(self, master):

            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            f = Frame(master, width=500, height=300)
            f.pack(fill=X, expand=True)

            mt = StringVar()


            menubar = Menu(master)
            menubar.add_command(label="New Game", command=self.new_game)
            menubar.add_command(label="Continue Game", command=self.continue_game)
            master.config(menu=menubar)

            maintext = Label(master, fg="blue", textvariable=mt)
            maintext.pack(side=BOTTOM)
            mt.set("")

            self.e1 = Entry(master)
            self.e1.pack()
            self.e1.bind("<Return>")
            self.e1.lower()


            global mt


        def new_game(self):
            mt.set("What do you want your username to be?")
            self.e1.lift()
            #wait for <Return> to be pressed
                mt.set("Welcome " + self.e1.get())
        def continue_game(self):
            mt.set("Type your username in.")



    root = Tk()

    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

I want it to be when I click "New Game" on the top menubar, it shows the entry box and waits for me to type something in, and then click enter.  THEN it prints out "Welcome"+(what the person types in).  What actually happens is when I click New game, it immediately just prints "Welcome".

By print, I mean aet the Label at the bottom to something else, which is reffered to by "mt.set".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GUI programs you don't wait* for something to happen, you respond to events. So, to call a function when the user presses return you would do something like:

```
    self.e1.bind("<Return>", self._on_return)
```

The above will call the function `_on_return` when the user presses the return key.

In your specific code you don't really need a StringVar. For example, you could do this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    self.maintext = Label(master, fg="blue")
    ...

def _on_return(self, event):
    self.maintext.configure(text="Welcome, %s" % self.e1.get())
```

* strictly speaking, you *can* wait for things, but that's not the right way to write GUI programs except under specific circumstances, such as waiting for a dialog to be dismissed.

Comment: also, how do i properly lift and lower the widgets? The way shown there doesn't really work, it gives me an error

Comment: What do you mean by "the way shown". This answer doesn't show how to call lift or lower. There's no trick to it though -- `mywidget.lift()` is all it takes.

Comment: I meant the way i tried to do it in my program shown there.  is "mywidget" in your comment interchangeble with the widget name?

Comment: You'll have to show the error, the code looks ok to me. And yes, 'mywidget' is interchangeable with your actual widget name. However, like I said in my answer, you can't wait for the user to input something, that's just not how GUI programming works.

Comment: where it say self.e1.lower, it doesnt actually hide the entry box, so what should I do to fix that? Also, when I remove the "self", it gives me this error:

NameError: global name 'e1' is not defined

Comment: Well, the problem is that it is already at the bottom of the stack - it can't be lowered below the main window. Using lower is highly unusual, I think it would be better if you stopped and worked through a tkinter tutorial before proceeding.